# Firestore Pagination, how to?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can't really seem to wrap my head around how this is done. Don't think the documentation is explaining it very well, or maybe I'm just not getting it :)

What I'm trying to do is have a list that start out by showing X items. Then with a click of a button load the next X items in the collection...

I've created this generic function which I can call:

```
let latestDoc = null;

export const getDocumentsPaginated = async <T extends { id?: string }>(collectionPath: string, numberOfDocs: number) => {
  const items: T[] = [];
  const q = query(collection(db, collectionPath), orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'), startAfter(latestDoc || 0), limit(numberOfDocs));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
  console.log('querySnapshot', querySnapshot)
  latestDoc = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const data = doc.data();
    items.push({
      ...data,
      id: doc.id
    } as T);
  });

  return items;
};
```

Then trying to call it from a Vue component:

```
const fetchExercises = async () => {
      isLoading.value = true;
      try {
        const result = await getDocumentsPaginated<ExerciseDocument>(`exercises/${companyId}/exercises`, 5);
        console.log('internal', result);
        exercises.value = result;
        isLoading.value = false;
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error('cant load exercises ' + e);
      }
    };
```

This does not seem to work. I just get an empty array back even though I know the collection has a lot of documents?

What am I doing wrong? Just really use a helping hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore pagination does **not** work based on offsets, so you're adding 20 to a counter will not work (as you've found).

---

Firestore pagination works based on [cursors object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors). This means that to query for the documents on the second page, you must know the data of the last item on the first page.

Since you `orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')`, you will need to know the `createdAt` value (and the document ID) of the last document on the first page, and pass those to `startAfter` to get the documents for the second page.

---

The easiest way to make pagination work in Firestore is to keep the `DocumentSnapshot` of the last item of the current page around in a variable with something like:

```
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
lastDocumentOnCurrentPage = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length-1];
```

Then when you need to load the next page of data, you pass this variable to the `startAfter` condition of the query.

Comment: I've updated the example to what you are mentioning, but I'm still getting back an empty array even though I know there is a lot of docs in the collection?

Comment: Please don't change your question like that, as now my answer makes no sense anymore to future visitors. --- The reason your original code didn't work is because you were passing in an offset instead of a cursor object, which is what I explained in my answer.  If you're having a hard time making it work with a cursor object, I recommend posting a new question for that with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).